# Missing feed targeting field for post with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to extract the 'feed_targeting' field for a created post using Facebook Graph API, but this information is missing when I try to get details of the post. I'm using the API v2.2 and according to the Facebook documentation this information should be there:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post?locale=en_GB.

1. First of all I created a post on my page and targeted it to a group of people.
2. Then I generated the Access Code with all permissions and used the Facebook Graph API Explorer to extract the post details.
3. Facebook correctly retrieves the post details but the information about targeting is missing in the response.

Let me know if I could give you any more information.

I'd appreciate if anybody could point me towards the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly specify the field for the `feed_targeting`? `GET /{post_id}?fields=id,message,feed_targeting`

Comment: Yes, of course. I tried feed_targeting and targeting - nothing works. The error I receive trying to get the fields is ""message": "(#602) targeting is not a member of the status table.".

Comment: When I'm using my mentioned call I don't receive an error. What is the Graph API version you're using?

Comment: The Graph API version I'm using is v2.2.

Comment: The `targeting` field doesn't exist: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post/

Comment: It's true, but the feed_targeting does exist.